# Software similar to Bitbucket that I can self host

Tags: mercurial

Is there a system similar to Bitbucket which I could self host? I've tried to look around in the net to see if there was something but I can't seem to find any. We're using Redmine right now but Redmine doesn't support multiple repositories per project.

Features of Bitbucket that I would like to be able to do would include the ability to fork a repository and to follow someone, make a pull request or something like that.

What are the good Mercurial tools out there?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the Bitbucket people do offer installations for customers, or at least that's what they said [on this thread on the bitbucket-users mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/bitbucket-users/browse_thread/thread/997bddb3c70bc05c)

Comment: @MartinGeisler: got any citation for that?

Comment: Ehm, hmm, sorry for not explaining myself properly. It's my impression that this went away when they got acquired by Atlassian. I think I got that after talking with Jesper Nøhr from Bitbucket at some Mercurial sprints. It would be cool to get it cleared up!

Comment: @MartinGeisler: could you please follow that up, then?

Comment: @MartinGeisler: any news, or has the enquiry fallen on the path and been eaten by the birds?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: no news so far, so it's probably eaten by those birds you talk about :-)

Comment: Atlassian now has a product called ''Stash'', a self-hosted Git installatian with useful features like LDAP and Jira integration. Unfortunately the pricing is quite enterprisey. https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview/

Comment: It seems mercurial support is currently not available. Ticket is https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-2469

Answer (score 12):

I found something that's nice: you can use [rhodecode](http://packages.python.org/RhodeCode/). It was really nice.

Answer (score 6):

They are Git based rather than Mercurial, but the software for [GitLab](https://www.gitlab.com/about/) and [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) are open source. [GitLab may now be a bit easier to setup and use than Gitorious](http://www.boxuk.com/blog/a-tale-of-three-git-systems/).

Answer (score 3):

Also found a really interesting project called [scm manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/Home)

Answer (score 2):

There was an early public hosting project called freehg for which the source was available.  The site appears down, but the author probably has the source somewhere still.

http://matthewmarshall.org/blog/2008/03/freehg.org/

Comment: Me neither, but email the guy.  I'm sure he'd be happy to have the code getting used.  I imagine you can contact him through his blog.

Answer (score 1):

BitBucket is very nice, but it is not available as download since Atlassian aquired the team.

I'm not sure if you consider commercial products, but [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/) and [CodeBeamer](http://www.intland.com/products/codebeamer) can be options to explore:

- Issue tracking, wiki, etc. are out of Kiln's scope, so you will need to keep your Redmine as well, what may or may not be an advantage.
- The features you mentioned (multiple repo per project, forking, pull requests) are supported by CodeBeamer, plus it is able to replace your Redmine instance completely.

(Disclaimer: Kiln is a FogCreek product, while CodeBeamer is a commercial software developed by our company)