# Is there a way to provide self-hosted web-based forking of Mercurial repos like BitBucket/Kiln?

Tags: mercurial, clone, bitbucket, fork, kiln

I'm currently using self-hosted SVN with Trac for a FOSS project, and am slowly moving to Mercurial. I've got HgWeb set up, so I can view the repository and check out over HTTP, but I'd like to be able to offer web-based branching a la BitBucket, Kiln and the like.

My server already has PHP and Python installed. Python is already taking up enough memory, so I don't think it'll cope with Java as well.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926351/software-similar-to-bitbucket-that-i-can-self-host), but there isn't a good answer and I don't need the full BitBucket feature set (basically just branch/clone and pull requests). There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473279/host-mercurial-on-my-companys-intranet) but it mainly got answers about simple hosting through HgWeb. There are also [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95977/bitbucket-or-alternatives) about BitBucket alternatives, but they focus on externally hosted options, and I want the control and integration with my existing Trac install.

So, are there any free options available that let my developer community make their own branches that they can check into so that I can easily pull from them to get changes into the Master repo?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you take a look on [RhodeCode](http://packages.python.org/RhodeCode/) which was suggested in one of the answers to the questions you linked to? I've just tried the demo and it looks impressive (alas, no Trac integration).

Comment: Just took a look - I must have missed it in the stacks of hosted options. Seems promising, and possibly the only option! Python-based, and it has a WSGI option as well. I'm not too worried about Trac integration for the forking and forked repos - that was more an issue of BitBucket not being a tight couple to my Trac, where as my Trac and local Mercurial would be. Thanks.

Comment: @Helgi you should make your answers answers not comments.

Comment: @Ry4an: You're probably right, I wasn't sure if IBBoard tried it yet, as it was listed in the answers of one of the linked questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Making an answer out of my comment, as [Ry4an](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8992/ry4an) suggested.*

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926351/software-similar-to-bitbucket-that-i-can-self-host/4985311#4985311), a system named [RhodeCode](http://rhodecode.org/) is mentioned, which its official site describes as

> Open source repository browser/management tool with a built in push/pull server, LDAP, permissions sytem and full text search.

It has web admin support, forks, and other server-side repo management. Even though it has no Trac integration, I myself consider it a better hosted option than `hgweb` which I use now.

Comment: I'm investigating it now. Only down-side is that I'm having to rebuild Subversion to make Swig bindings for Python 2.6, because CentOS 5 has Python 2.4 and RhodeCode requires 2.5. There isn't a "pull request" feature yet, but I think my project is small enough to manage without that for now :) Thanks.

Comment: @IBBoard: Oops, I was sure I saw pull requests in the demo. The site of RhodeCode is currently down for some reason, but from the docs it looks like this is not implemented (yet?).

Comment: The page won't load at the moment, but according to the email list on Google then https://bitbucket.org/marcinkuzminski/rhodecode/issue/127/pull-request is the feature request for pull requests. When I read it at work it was targetted at v1.3 and needed an internal messaging system. I _think_ it supports pull/push in terms of normal Hg pull/push, though (i.e. HgWeb replacement).